# Attaching method to execute for an Event

Tags: c#, events

I got an event from special API I'm working with, the event I'm working with is defined as

```
public event EventHandler<QuoteEventArgs> OnQuote


public class QuoteEventArgs : EventArgs
```

so what I'm trying to do is attach a method to run when I got a new `Quote` listening to this event.

so what I do is:

```
myInstance.OnQuote += new EventHandler<QuoteEventArgs>(doThis);
```

And the method is defined as:

```
public void doThis(object sender, QuoteEventArgs e){

//code here..

}
```

The error I get is:

> Cannot implicity convert type `'System.EventHandler<MT4API.QuoteEventArgs>'` to `'System.EventHandler'`

but I don't seem to have a special eventHandler on the API either, so not quite sure how to make that work.

Comment: There are two classes called `System.EventHandler` – one is generic and one isn't. Are you sure the `OnQuote` event is using the generic one?

Comment: This is the documentation http://tradingapi.net/mt4-api-doc/html/e56fcbc1-da9e-d98d-c81c-07f83471e90f.htm  the eventhandler class goes to this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x

Comment: You might still be using a different version of the library than the one that's documented. (One from before C# got generics.) When you mouse over `OnQuote` in Visual Studio, is the event type in the tooltip `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<QuoteEventArgs>`?

Comment: it says: EventHandler MT4.OnQuote (line break here) Enable  OnQuoteMode in DotNetApi EA to use this event

Comment: ok, so the type of the event is EventHandler, not EventHandler<QuoteEventArgs>. You are using a different version of the library from the one which your documentation is referring to. In your version the event has a non-generic type.

Comment: if I change to EventHandler and change the method to EventArgs the error goes away, but then of course I cannot use the QuoteEventArgs properties...

Comment: which is funny, I know the version I'm using the latest version, and that is 3.1 newer than 2.9 :(

Comment: Ok, I will contact the API developer to see what is going on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @George You're still likely getting a `QuoteEventArgs` instance passed into your event handler. Just cast the `e` parameter to `QuoteEventArgs`

Comment: interesting!, will try that out! thanks Inerdial!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment discussion, it appears that you are using a version of the library in which the event does not have a generic type, i.e. the signature is

```
public event EventHandler OnQuote;
```

This means you will also have to consume it in a non-generic way:-

```
myInstance.OnQuote += new EventHandler(doThis);

public void doThis(object sender, EventArgs e){

   var myArgs = (QuoteEventArgs)e;
   ...
}
```

Comment: That was it, although casting EventArgs to QuoteEventArgs didn't work, looks like that part of the API was not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there are two classes with the name `QuoteEventArgs`, perhaps one from a referenced DLL and one from a generated proxy.  Ensure that if you've got usings that the usings are correct.